# Find the non negative continuous function defined over $[0,1]$ and satisfy given equations

Tags: calculus

Find the non negative continuous function defined over $[0,1]$ such that $$\int_0^1 x^kf(x){\rm d}x=a^k,$$ where $k=0,1,2$ and $a\in[0,1]$

solution i try

from $$\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx=1\cdots (1)\times a^2$$

and $$\int^{1}_{0}x\cdot f(x)dx=a\cdots (2)\times 2a$$

and $$\int^{1}_{0}x^2\cdot f(x)dx=a^2\cdots (3)$$

getting $$\int^{1}_{0}(x-a)^2f(x)dx=0$$

how i get functions which satisfy given equation, help required

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the last equality the integrand is non-negative and zero at no more than a single point. The only solution to this equation is $f(x)=0$. Hence this is the only solution for $a=0$ and there are no such $f(x) $ for $a\in(0,1]$.